# How to make a space between <i> tags (icons) in table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a classic HTML table. In one column I want to add 3 icons with links to edit for example users. I am using twitter-bootstrap and glyphsicons. How to make more space between icons???
I prefer to use CSS.

```
<td>
   <a href='#'>
       <i class='icon-ok'></i>
   </a>
   <a href='#'> 
       <i class='icon-pencil'></i> 
   </a> 
   <a href='#'>
       <i class='icon-remove'></i>
   </a>
</td>
```

Comment: td a i { padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; }

Comment: i { display: block; margin: 0 5px; }.  You can change the selector to be more specific and 5px to the space width you want

Comment: @Stefan Brendle YES very good THANKS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just apply a padding (or a margin, depending on the style you've used) between elements, e.g.

```
td a + a {
   padding-left: 3em;
}
```

Comment: it ran like a charm

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `padding` attribute in `style` tag.

```
<td>
    <a href='#'><i class='icon-ok'></i></a>
    <a style="padding-left:25px;" href='#'><i class='icon-pencil'></i></a>
    <a style="padding-left:25px;" href='#'><i class='icon-remove'></i></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add padding; like so:

```
i {
padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In css you can add a margin to your

```
a {margin-right: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give them a right padding (margin doesn't work on inline elements):

```
.icon-ok { padding-right: 1em; }
.icon-pencil { padding-right: 1em; }
```

If you want to avoid the space after the last icon, you can give the surrounding table cell a negative right margin (so the two eliminate each other) or use more complex CSS rules to cancel the last gap.

Answer (score 0):

Normally *a* tags are inline elements. So, the box-model is not what you expect. I'll suggest

```
a {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```